# Pivot table to convert rows to columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

| NAME | OCCUPATION |
| --- | --- |
| Samantha | Doctor |
| Julia | Actor |
| Maria | Actor |
| Meera | Singer |
| Ashley | Professor |
| Ketty | Professor |
| Christeen | Professor |
| Jane | Actor |
| Jenny | Doctor |
| Priya | Singer |

Hi I have  a *table* **occupation** as above

I want the output to be like

| Doctor | Professor | Singer | Actor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jenny | Ashley | Meera | Jane |
| Samantha | Christeen | Priya | Julia |
| NULL | Ketty | NULL | Maria |

I tried this SELECT Statement below but it is not working as expected :

```
SELECT rank,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation='Doctor' THEN name ELSE NULL END) AS Doctor,
       MAX(CASE WHEN occupation='Professor' THEN name ELSE NULL END) AS Professor,
       MAX(CASE WHEN occupation='Singer' THEN name ELSE NULL END) AS Singer,
       MAX(CASE WHEN occupation='Actor' THEN name ELSE NULL END) AS Actor
  FROM
  (     
    SELECT o1.Occupation,
           o1.name,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM Occupations o2 
             WHERE o1.Occupation=o2.Occupation 
               AND o1.name > o2.name ) rank       
      FROM Occupations o1)
 GROUP BY rank
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to sort the results by `name` column along with an analytic function such as [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ROW_NUMBER.html#GUID-D5A157F8-0F53-45BD-BF8C-AE79B1DB8C41) provided that the version of your database is at least **9i** such as

```
SELECT rank,
       MAX(CASE WHEN occupation='Doctor' THEN name END) AS doctor,
       MAX(CASE WHEN occupation='Professor' THEN name END) AS professor,
       MAX(CASE WHEN occupation='Singer' THEN name END) AS singer,
       MAX(CASE WHEN occupation='Actor' THEN name END) AS actor
  FROM (     
        SELECT Occupation, name,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY occupation ORDER BY name)-1 rank       
          FROM Occupations
       )
 GROUP BY rank  
 ORDER BY rank
```

where using `ELSE NULL` case is redundant.

**OR**

you can alternatively use **PIVOT** clause

```
SELECT *
  FROM (     
        SELECT occupation, name,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY occupation ORDER BY name)-1 rank       
          FROM Occupations
       )
 PIVOT (
        MAX(name) FOR occupation IN ('Doctor'    AS "Doctor",
                                     'Professor' AS "Professor",
                                     'Singer'    AS "Singer",
                                     'Actor'     AS "Actor")
       )     
 ORDER BY rank
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=17aff94dde9fad10bb197f7915d7f4f6)</kbd>